# Data table/grid widget with Backbone.js

Tags: jquery, widget, backbone.js, datatables

Can any one suggest a data table/grid widget to use in a application backed by Backbone.js & jQuery?

Currently I m using DataTables.net widget, and I've written a custom binding sort of functions for Backbone.js. But binding with Backbone and its API are seems complex to me. Is there any widget which is simple and with clean & clever API (I liked YUI grid, but to use the grid alone JS size is around 360KB+)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just released [Backgrid.js](http://wyuenho.github.com/backgrid).

Backgrid.js is a powerful set of widgets for building data grids on top of Backbone.js in 4.7K. It generates semantic HTML so its extremely stylable and  customizable. The core works on mobile and comes with lots of extensions for many extra features too.

Comment: Nice one, but not compatible with ie7.

Comment: Nope. Nobody should support the 2%.

Comment: @YHWong Sure thing. Too bad my boss doesn't think that way.

Comment: @darksoulsong I would look for a new job if they want to support IE7 :)

Comment: @Y.HWong you sir, are amazing and this is an incredibly written tool as well.  Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a fan of http://tablesorter.com

it's a jquery plugin that turns any standard html `<table>` element into a sortable, pageable grid. and since it's just a jquery plugin, there's no conflicts or any special considerations for using it with backbone

really, though, any jquery table / grid plugin should work

Comment: I considered using Table sorter, which is actually a good one. Using any widget with Backbone, I m required to customize the widget to get the data via collections/models. This becomes a bit more complex (not much though) when I need some CRUD operations on the datatable rows

Comment: that sounds like a fun problem to solve, though. i may have to write up a sample app and do a blog post, just for fun :)

Comment: hey should the above quote be put somewhere for future historical reference?

Answer (score 4):

> Slickback is a javascript library that adapts Backbone collections to
>   work with SlickGrid, a jQuery-backed datagrid. Extensions include
>   support for paginating collections

Demo: http://teleological.github.com/slickback/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try https://github.com/charly/backbone.grid (Disclosure: I created it). Beware I still use it to fit my own needs but I'm hoping it'll get mature enough for a public release. Contribution/remarks are welcome...

Example code :

```
App.Views.AModel.EditView = Grid.EditView.extend({
  tagName : "tr",
  className : "new_matter",
  template : JST["templates/matters/show"],

  initialize : function() {
    this.model.bind("sync", this.renderRow, this);
  }
  //...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this. [bbGrid](https://github.com/direct-fuel-injection/bbGrid). Just in work, right now.